# помогите заполнить вектор другими векторами

Tags: c++, vector, вектор

````
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<vector<int>> languagesGid[255];
vector<vector<int>> languagesVis[100];

int main()
{
    
    ifstream inf("input.txt");
    ofstream outf("output.txt");
    int countGid;
    int countVis;
    int countLangGid;
    int countLangVis;
    int t;

    inf >> countGid;
    inf >> countVis;

    vector<int> languages;
    for (int i = 0; i < countGid; i++) {
        inf >> countLangGid;
        
        for (int j = 0; j < countLangGid; j++) {
            inf >> t;
            languages[j] = t;
        }
       languagesGid.push_back(languages);
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот это:

```
vector<vector<int>> languagesGid[255];
```

массив из 255 элементов, где каждый элемент является вектором векторов, то есть эта запись задает вектор векторов векторов.

Вот это:

```
vector<vector<int>> languagesGid(255);
```

вектор состоящий из 255 элементов, где каждый элемент является пустым вектором.

То есть в первом случае создается С-style массив, а во втором работает конструктор `std::vector`.

Comment: `vector<vector<int>> languagesGid[255];` - это C-style массив из 255 `vector<vector<int>>`.